# Face recognition using deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, face-recognition

I am trying to build face recognition system using siemens network. I am using PubFig database. It is a large, real-world face dataset consisting of 58,797 images of 200 people collected from the internet. So from scratch I am trying to build this face recognition system using siemes network. So is this approach is good for face recognition from scratch? (I don't want to use transfer learning I want to build it from scratch)

Answer (score 0):

See Papers With Code https://paperswithcode.com/task/face-recognition for the State of the Art on this task. A review of how other people have approached a particular task is the best starting point for developing a new solution.

Comment: What is your opinion about siemens network for face recognition?

Comment: If you mean siamese networks, then I guess you could get a reasonably good result.